# Select sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server

[image: Todos los registros]

Hola Amigos una consulta en sql server 2014.

Como puedo obtener los registros con fecha mas actual de cada grupo.

Como en la imagen que adjunto.Lo que quiero lograr es que me traiga la Revision 1 y la revision 0 pero de ambas con su insert de fecha mas actual. y que coincidan los registros.
Lo que quiero lograr es lo de la segunda imagen.

He intentado con este codigo pero solo me trae un registro. Agradeceria mucho si alguien me pudiera orientar.

```
SELECT T1.clave, 
       T1.titulo, 
       T1.revision, 
       T1.fecharevision, 
       T1.revisadopor, 
       T1. aprobadopor, 
       T1.nombrearchivo, 
       T1.descripcionarchivo, 
       T1.claverelacionada, 
       T1.archivo, 
       T1.link, 
       T1.fecharevlast, 
       T1.estatus 
FROM   motoresemis AS T1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(fecharevlast) AS FechaRevLast, 
                          revision 
                   FROM   motoresemis 
                   GROUP  BY revision) AS T2 
               --INNER JOIN Area1 A on T1.ID=A.IdTitulo  
               ON T1.fecharevlast = T2.fecharevlast 
                  AND T1.clave = 'CMD-01' 
ORDER  BY T1.fecharevlast DESC
```

[image: los registros que quiero obtener]

Answer (score 1):

Primero sería partir los datos por el campo `revision` y ordenarlos por el campo `fecharevlast`, con eso agregar un número de fila para que el primer registro de cada grupo sea 1.

```
SELECT *, 
        Row_number() 
        OVER( 
           partition BY revision 
            ORDER BY fecharevlast DESC ) AS orden
```

Después crear una consulta sobre el resultado de la consulta anterior para filtrar solo los registros con `orden = 1`

```
SELECT T1.clave, 
           T1.titulo, 
           T1.revision, 
           T1.fecharevision, 
           T1.revisadopor, 
           T1. aprobadopor, 
           T1.nombrearchivo, 
           T1.descripcionarchivo, 
           T1.claverelacionada, 
           T1.archivo, 
           T1.link, 
           T1.fecharevlast, 
           T1.estatus 
    FROM   (SELECT *, 
                   Row_number() 
                     OVER( 
                       partition BY revision 
                       ORDER BY fecharevlast DESC ) AS orden 
            FROM   motoresemis) AS T1 
    WHERE  T1.clave = 'CMD-01' AND T1.orden = 1
```

[Referencia clausula over](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax)